# Looking for a general pointer on how to show live console output in a window using Handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

Using Handlebars, express, and node.js; I've got a shell script that's triggered after an HTML form is filled out. The script -- which runs on the server -- outputs nicely via console.log:

```
builder.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
    });
}
```

The console shows exactly what it should. However, I need to feed that output in (near) real-time  to the client in a window so [s]he can watch the progress of the script. I have the following in my template:

```
<div>
    <fieldset style="width:1200px" id="outputWindow">

    ... want the output text here ...

</div>
```

I've searched for a "clean" way to implement redirection to a client browser but thus far have been unsuccessful in finding one; most of what I've found revolves around polling updates, and I'd prefer to avoid that. Not asking for a complete solution, but can someone point me in the general direction of an accepted way to redirect this asynchronous output so that it will display on the client's browser in that  area?

Thanks!

Comment: "I want to do X" isn't really what SO is for. It's for "I wanted to do X, so I wrote code Y, and I ran into a problem". If you want to push data from your server to some client browser, you'll have to read up on how push communication between express and a browser works (short answer: web sockets), and then read through some tutorials that show you how to set that up. And then once you do that, and you're convinced you did it right, but it doesn't work, and despite debugging you can't figure out why, _that's_ the right time to post to SO.

Comment: you have two ways of accomplishing live data, you can either poll the data (send an HTTP request somewhere every N seconds to retrieve changes) or the better option - you can use something called websockets with socket.io

Comment: Seems like a problem solved by [WebSocket's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API), not handlebars

Comment: Yeah then you definitely abused SO a little. You could have found this out by doing some [searching and researching](/help/how-to-ask) first, by searching for the result you wanted and working backwards to finding the terms for what that is called, and then searching for that to find any of hundreds of tutorials. Is that more work? Yes. Are you expected to do that before posting? Also yes ;)

Comment: awesome, but in that case the posting guidelines are pretty clear: mention that. Nothing wrong with asking on SO as your last resort, but then make sure your post makes it clear that it is, and that you already did your due diligence. (and note that now is the best time to still edit your post to make that clear, because then none of these comments need to keep existing and I'll happily delete mine after the first one)

Comment: Edited per request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show realtime output of `console.log` in browser you have many ways.

The first way is using [websocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket).

> Can you see example how to implement server side and client side:
> https://github.com/websockets/ws/tree/master/examples

But if you want to receive only output of console.log I advise you to use [EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource)

> Can you see example how to implement server side and client side:
> https://github.com/EventSource/eventsource/tree/master/example